# Difference between `mle` and `optimize` functions in R

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood

I am trying some examples in R about maximum likelihood estimation, and it seems that we can use both the `optimize` function of the "stats" package and the `mle` function of the "stats4" package for this task?

Is it fair to say that `optimize` is a more generic version of `mle`?
One thing I notice is the the `mle` function requires an initial seed value (intelligent guesses), but the `optimize` function does not. Why is this?

Answer (score 6):

The [docs](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/stats4/mle) for `mle` say:

> The optim optimizer is used to find the minimum of the negative log-likelihood. An approximate covariance matrix for the parameters is obtained by inverting the Hessian matrix at the optimum.

So, in fact, `mle` uses `optim` internally.  Looks like `mle` does some after the fact work to give the caller back data in an object that has some convenience methods attached for tasks specific to maximum likelihood estimation.

As far as I know, `optim` also requires initial values.  From the `optim` [docs](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/stats/optim):

> par:
>   Initial values for the parameters to be optimized over.

is the first argument to `optim`.

The `optimize` function, on the other hand, can only handle one variable optimization problems, so is considerably less general than `optim`.  It does not use a gradient based approach

> The method used is a combination of golden section search and successive parabolic interpolation

Here's a reference for [that method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search).  Since it is not gradient based, it does not need a starting point, instead working by "chopping up" the interval into smaller and smaller pieces, each of which bound a local extrema.

Comment: I didnt provide an initial value here:x <- mtcars$am;

L <- function(p, x) prod(dbinom(x, size = 1, prob = p));

optimize(L, interval = c(0, 1), x = x, maximum = TRUE);

Comment: Ahh, there is an `optimize`.  I think that only handles one variable optimization.  I'll take a look and add it to my answer in a bit.  My guess is that its choice of the initial point is somewhat arbitrary.